# как сделать запрос через requests.get() в python

Tags: python, requests, curl

как сделать запрос через  `requests.get()` в python, если надо преобразовать curl запрос `curl -H "X-Bit-Access-Key: Your Access Key" "https://betaapi.bitexch.dev/v1/wallet/spot-deposits?currency=BTC&limit=10&offset=0&timestamp=1589522687689&signature=signature"`
Это надо для того, чтобы я мог связаться со своим аккаунтом биржи bit.com
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ получен с помощью https://curlconverter.com/

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Bit-Access-Key': 'Your Access Key',
}

params = {
    'currency': 'BTC',
    'limit': '10',
    'offset': '0',
    'timestamp': '1589522687689',
    'signature': 'signature',
}

response = requests.get('https://betaapi.bitexch.dev/v1/wallet/spot-deposits', params=params, headers=headers)
```